# Android: enable temporary touch/click for all views but one

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I have a set of buttons and views displayed on the screen. At some point, I would like to be able to interact only with one of them and block all the others. 
And I need to retain all the listeners to restore theirs behaviors later.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For disabling buttons, when you clicking on a specific button/view, disable other buttons/views in the specific onClickListener like

```
//button1 onClickListener
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                button2.setClickable(false); //disable button2
                view1.setClickable(false); //disable view1
            }
        });
```

likewise for all other buttons and views, then you may enable those by calling

```
button2.setClickable(true);
view1.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: thakns, but I would like to do something generic, so I can re-use it easily later on, with other views etc.

Comment: meaning I dont want to make the list of all the views I need to disable. Actually I dont even know it!